# JQuery loop through output buffer using .each()

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop

Okay I have a function that gets vine tweets and then displays the video via an iFrame. This works great the only problem is I don't want to list them all at once, I just want one to display then once finished display the next one. It is probably quite simple but I have been looking at the code to long and now I can't think straight. Please help.

```
         function getTweets() {
                    var url='http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=givingvine';
                    $.getJSON(url,function(json){

                    //setup an array to buffer output
                    var output = [];

                    //a for loop will perform faster when setup like this
                    for (var i = 0, len = json.results.length; i < len; i++) {
                   //instead of appending each result, add each to the buffer array
                   output.push('<p>' + '<iframe class="video" src="' + json.results[i].text.substr(json.results[i].text.indexOf("http")) +'" frameborder="0" width="1080" height="800" style="margin:-155px -100px -130px -60px;"></iframe>' + '</p>');

                    }

                //now select the #results element only once and append all the output at once, then slide it into view
                  $.each(output, function (intIndex, objValue) {
                    $("#results").html(objValue);
                    });
                });
                }
                 //set an interval to run the getTweets function (30,000 ms is 5 minutes), you can cancel the interval by calling clearInterval(timer);
                 var timer = setInterval(getTweets, 10000);
                clearInterval(timer);
                //run the getTweets function on document.ready
                getTweets();

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to store your results in output, then only append the first one to #results. Then when a user does something add another one?

I would suggest you store the current "place" in a variable and then when a user does what you want to add the next one, increment it by 1

something like

```
  var output =[],currentKey =0;
  function getTweets() {
                var url='http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=vine';
                $.getJSON(url,function(json){

                //setup an array to buffer output


                //a for loop will perform faster when setup like this
                for (var i = 0, len = json.results.length; i < len; i++) {
               //instead of appending each result, add each to the buffer array
               output.push('<p>' + '<iframe class="video" src="' + json.results[i].text.substr(json.results[i].text.indexOf("http")) +'" frameborder="0" width="1080" height="800" style="margin:-155px -100px -130px -60px;"></iframe>' + '</p>');

                }

            //now select the #results element only once and append all the output at once, then slide it into view
                $("#results").html(output[currentKey]);
            });
            }

         getTweets();

        $('#next').click(function(){
          currentKey +=1;
          if(currentKey  < output.length){
         $('#results').append(output[currentKey]);   
       }
       });
```

The example above assumes you have some kind of button with an id=next that when clicked appends the next item to results e.g

```
  <button id="next">Next Video</button>
```

If you want to replace the current video then use

```
        $('#results').html(output[currentKey]);   
       //  instead of
       $('#results').append(output[currentKey]);
```

Comment: This is somewhat what I am looking for, I don't want a button I want it to switch after a specific interval

Comment: Then replace the "click" function with a window.setInterval(function(){ //code from above in click function here }, 10000); //10 seconds The interval should prob be stored in a variable so you can kill it when the length of items has been reached

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Sounds like you would want something like this:

```
output.push('<p>' + '<iframe id="iframe' + i.toString() + '"  class="video" src="' + json.results[i].text.substr(json.results[i].text.indexOf("http")) +'" frameborder="0" width="1080" height="800" style="margin:-155px -100px -130px -60px;"></iframe>' + '</p>');

                    }
```

Then in here:

```
              $.each(output, function (intIndex, objValue) {
                $("#results").html(objValue);
                //Some Timer code here;
                //Remove previous iframe, add a new iframe
                $('#results').empty();
                });
```

You could also however change the forloop to populate output with the src and then in the foreach do something like this:

```
              $.each(output, function (intIndex, objValue) {
                $("#iframe").attr('src', objValue)
                //Some Timer code here;
                });
```

---

If you want to display an iframe one at a time with your setup:

You may want to use the each() function:

```
$.each(output, function (intIndex, objValue) {
     $("#results").html(objValue);
});
```

In place of the:

```
$("#results").html(output);
```

Comment: Yes this is close to what I want. What would I add to make the iframe switch to the next one in the array?

Comment: For that instead of selecting results and applying the html, you would need to select the iframe - via its class or by adding an ID attribute to the tag. So something like $('iframe').html(objValue);

Comment: I am really not that great with JQuery, How would i be able to do this with the iframe being generated inside the for loop?